# How to find the distance to each segment of my route from random Points?

Tags: postgresql, distance

I want to find the distance from each point to each segment to one route to find the nearest segment.

```
with myroute as (select ST_MakeLine(array[
                ST_Point(11.507663726806642, 48.153947660519925)
                , ST_Point(11.574354171752931, 48.147476832888955)
                , ST_Point(11.5631103515625, 48.12530949732785)  
                , ST_Point(11.65477752685547, 48.09321578710874)
                ]) as geom 
            )
, mypoints as (SELECT 
                (ST_DUMPPOINTS
                        (ST_GeneratePoints
                            (ST_MakeEnvelope(11.513469, 48.083019, 11.643909, 48.193572), 10, 4328)
                        )
                ).geom
               )
select * from myroute, mypoints;
```